# How to use the "ngFor" without repeating the element you've applied it on?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Sorry, I can't post all the code here. But, if you could give me some hint as to what needs to be done, I'd appreciate it.

Let me try to explain my predicament.

So, this is the code snippet I've been trying to use `ngFor` and `ngIf` on:

```
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let option of question.options">
          <div class="form-check lead">
            <input
              class="form-check-input"
              type="checkbox"
              value=""
              id="{{ option.id }}"
              [(ngModel)]="option.selected"
              (change)="onSelect(question, option)"
              disabled="disabled"
            />
            <label
              class="form-check-label d-block fw-normal"
              [attr.for]="option.id"
            >
              {{ option.name }}
              <ng-container *ngFor="let obj of response"
                ><fa-icon
                  *ngIf="
                    obj.qId == option.questionId && obj.correct.includes(option.id)
                  "
                  [icon]="faCheck"
                ></fa-icon
              ></ng-container>
            </label>
            <div>
              <img
                src="{{ option.image }}"
                alt=""
                onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"
                width="55"
                height="55"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
```

Before this code there is this element,

`<div class="d-flex flex-column bg-white px-5" *ngFor="let question of filteredQuestions" style="white-space: pre-line">`

`filteredQuestions()` loads the array of objects in which there are questions and inside of a question, there is array of `options`.

Now, what I want is to display the `check` icon right next to the correct option.

This is the `response` array:

```
response = [
{ qId: '60e57c069107a038085ae3a1', correct: [1001, 1002] },
{ qId: '60e57cc09107a038085ae3a2', correct: [1002] },
{ qId: '60e57d289107a038085ae3a3', correct: [1003] },
{ qId: '60e57d9e9107a038085ae3a4', correct: [1001, 1002, 1003] },
{ qId: '60e57e7c9107a038085ae3a5', correct: [1004] }];
```

This is the overall structure for the options:

```
[{id: number;
  questionId: number;
  name: string;
  image: string;
  selected: boolean;}]
```

I've tried to use the `ngFor` on different tags but with no luck. Right now, there are no check icons based on the if condition on the fa-icon tag.

And when I remove the `ngIf` from the fa-icon tag in this case, the checks just print multiple times. Where can I apply the tag so that the element won't repeat and I can get my desired output?

Comment: Please put your code in stackblitz.com to make sense. runnable code might be helpful

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Would it be alright if I put my code in GitHub repo?

Comment: Yes It's Ok. But Also you can put the code here  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngcontainer too and fork them and send url here

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi It's asking me to be a pro member when I try to upload something.

Comment: But stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngcontainer is free just click on it and put your code and run it and click of Fork and send the URL

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Alright, let me try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235103/discussion-between-ab1004-and-alireza-ahmadi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `option.id` is not number, so this `obj.correct.includes(option.id)` was not satisfied and does not meet your `*ngIf` condition in below line of code:

```
<fa-icon *ngIf="obj.qId == option.questionId && obj.correct.includes(+option.id)" [icon]="faCheck"></fa-icon>
```

So easy way to solve the problem is that put `+` next to the `option.id`:

```
obj.correct.includes(+option.id)

<ng-container *ngFor="let obj of response">
    <fa-icon *ngIf="obj.qId == option.questionId && obj.correct.includes(+option.id)" [icon]="faCheck"></fa-icon>
</ng-container>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-font-awesome-starter-ojplfk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquiz%2Fquiz.component.html) is working sample

And the result:

[image]

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you for taking your time out to answer this!

Comment: Could you think of an if condition so that only options that are selected and are not correct have cross icon right next to them?

Comment: look at my code. I put some js code in the function of `onSubmit`. So you know option is corrected and which is selected

Comment: I put it here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-font-awesome-starter-jdzvl8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquiz%2Fquiz.component.html

Comment: Thank You again! One last question, if it's not a nuisance at this point. I want to generate a response that I could send on to the back-end. What I want is to generate an array of objects. And each object would contain a questionId and the Ids of selected options in an array. Could you also shine a light on this problem?

Comment: I think questionId and selected answer that would be enough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235110/discussion-between-ab1004-and-alireza-ahmadi).